# How to get second duplicate value rather than first value from JSON Array in React JS using lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, lodash

I am working on one project where I need to remove duplicate values from JSON array object with some specification in react JS. I have tried to remove using **_.uniqBy** but in the output it took very first value from duplicate value which is I don't want.

Suppose You have an array JSON like:

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'bob' }, { id: 2, name: 'bill' }, { id: 1, name: 'alice' } ]
```

using **_.uniqBy** I got `[ { id: 1, name: 'bob' }, { id: 2, name: 'bill' }]` this output.

but I want `[ { id: 2, name: 'bill' }, { id: 1, name: 'alice' } ]` this output.

As you can see I want output whose name is alice not bob along with `id:1`.

**Can anyone help me?
Thank you.**

Comment: Unique by what?

Comment: So you want always the last ones be the valid ones?

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to do this? If you need ideas, you can look at the source code of lodash: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2f79053d7bc7c9c9561a30dda202b3dcd2b72b90/.internal/baseUniq.js

Comment: yes @OriDrori I want last ones not first ones. and _.uniqBy is method to remove the duplicates from JSON object. If you want to know more vist [link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to use a reduce, and shove the items in a map, then get the values:

```
   Object.values(items.reduce((map, item) => ({ ...map, [item.id]: item }), {}))
```

This is probably not very efficient though if you're dealing with large arrays of have performance concerns.

It's a quick and dirty one-liner. If you want something more efficient I'd take a look at the lodash source code and tweak it to your needs or write something similar:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2f79053d7bc7c9c9561a30dda202b3dcd2b72b90/.internal/baseUniq.js

Comment: Quite impressive @Joe!